# iPhone + UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I have UINavigationController in my application, at some point I hide NavigationBar using following code:

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

Because of this my View is disturbed and there is a gap displayed at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding 20px to the view's frame height. You could try using autoresizessubviews & autoresizingmask

Comment: how to do u add 20px to view's frame height

Comment: Don't have xcode open, but it should be something like:

    CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
    newFrame.size.height += 20;
    self.view.frame = newFrame;